# How to use Route53 NS output to set NS for Cloudflare subdomain using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, terraform

I have created a Zone In AWS Route53 as following

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "my-app" {
  name = "${var.zone_name}"

}
data "aws_route53_zone" "selected" {
  name = "appgggghello.com."
}

output "ns" {
  value = "${data.aws_route53_zone.selected.name_servers}"
}
```

it will show out put as below

```
ns = [
    ns-754.awsdns-350.net,
    ns-555.awsdns-0553.org,
    ns-555.awsdns-25552.co.uk,
    ns-45569.awsdns-55555.com
]
```

Now i have question is how can i use this NS output as input in Cloudfalre like here

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "aws-ns-record" {
  domain = "${var.domain}"
  name   = "appgggghello.com"
  value = ["${data.aws_route53_zone.selected.name_servers}"]
  type     = "NS"
  priority = 1
}
```

Within Route53 i can set NS using

```
records = ["${data.aws_route53_zone.selected.name_servers}"]
```

Please let me know how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cloudflare_record` takes a string for value not a list

```
value - (Optional) The (string) value of the record. Either this or data must be specified
```

So we need to add a count in there

Now i have question is how can i use this NS output as input in Cloudfalre like here. Then pull the element out of the list based on the count

```
resource "cloudflare_record" "aws-ns-record" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_route53_zone.selected.name_servers)}"
  domain = "${var.domain}"
  name   = "appgggghello.com"
  value = "${element(data.aws_route53_zone.selected.name_servers, count.index)}"
  type     = "NS"
  priority = 1
}
```

Comment: i have tried but getting error ```Error: cloudflare_record.aws-ns-record: value must be a single value, not a list```

Comment: sorry i left brackets around the value.. see the current answer for them removed and try that

Comment: Now its working

Comment: Now getting ```count``` error. its known issue. do you have any workaround? ```cloudflare_record.aws-ns-record: value of 'count' cannot be computed```